# Is there a builtin command or a workaround to generate a nested sum (of apropriate level) from an expanded expression?

Tags: summation, subscript, index

I have the following output from some Mathematica manipulation of nested sums. Does Mathematica have a command or combination of commands that recovers nested sums from the  expanded form?

> $$\begin{align}
> &b_2 \left(c_{2,2} \left(d_{2,2} e_{2,2}\right)\right)+\\
> &b_3 \left(c_{3,2} \left(d_{2,2} e_{2,2}\right)+c_{3,3} \left(d_{3,2} e_{2,2}+d_{3,3} e_{3,2}\right)\right)+\\
> &b_4 \left(c_{4,2} \left(d_{2,2} e_{2,2}\right)+c_{4,3} \left(d_{3,2} e_{2,2}+d_{3,3} e_{3,2}\right)+c_{4,4} \left(d_{4,2} e_{2,2}+d_{4,3} e_{3,2}+d_{4,4} e_{4,2}\right)\right)+\\
> &b_5 \left(c_{5,2} \left(d_{2,2} e_{2,2}\right)+c_{5,3} \left(d_{3,2} e_{2,2}+d_{3,3} e_{3,2}\right)+c_{5,4} \left(d_{4,2} e_{2,2}+d_{4,3} e_{3,2}+d_{4,4} e_{4,2}\right)+c_{5,5} \left(d_{5,2} e_{2,2}+d_{5,3} e_{3,2}+d_{5,4} e_{4,2}+d_{5,5} e_{5,2}\right)\right)+\\
> &\vdots\\
> \end{align}$$

This would require this command/code to generate Mathematica code. Something like:

```
Sum[Subscript[b, i]Sum[?Sum[?,{k,?,?}],{j,?,?}],{i,0,MyMax}]
```

Or, eventually $LaTeX$ code.

```
Subscript[b, 2]*Subscript[c, 2, 2]*Subscript[d, 2, 2]*Subscript[e, 2, 2] + Subscript[b, 3]*Subscript[c, 3, 2]*Subscript[d, 2, 2]*Subscript[e, 2, 2] + 
  Subscript[b, 5]*Subscript[c, 5, 2]*Subscript[d, 2, 2]*Subscript[e, 2, 2] + Subscript[b, 6]*Subscript[c, 6, 2]*Subscript[d, 2, 2]*Subscript[e, 2, 2] + 
  Subscript[b, 7]*Subscript[c, 7, 2]*Subscript[d, 2, 2]*Subscript[e, 2, 2] + Subscript[b, 3]*Subscript[c, 3, 3]*Subscript[d, 3, 2]*Subscript[e, 2, 2] + 
  Subscript[b, 5]*Subscript[c, 5, 3]*Subscript[d, 3, 2]*Subscript[e, 2, 2] + Subscript[b, 6]*Subscript[c, 6, 3]*Subscript[d, 3, 2]*Subscript[e, 2, 2] + 
  Subscript[b, 7]*Subscript[c, 7, 3]*Subscript[d, 3, 2]*Subscript[e, 2, 2] + Subscript[b, 5]*Subscript[c, 5, 4]*Subscript[d, 4, 2]*Subscript[e, 2, 2] + 
  Subscript[b, 6]*Subscript[c, 6, 4]*Subscript[d, 4, 2]*Subscript[e, 2, 2] + Subscript[b, 7]*Subscript[c, 7, 4]*Subscript[d, 4, 2]*Subscript[e, 2, 2] + 
  Subscript[b, 5]*Subscript[c, 5, 5]*Subscript[d, 5, 2]*Subscript[e, 2, 2] + Subscript[b, 6]*Subscript[c, 6, 5]*Subscript[d, 5, 2]*Subscript[e, 2, 2] + 
  Subscript[b, 7]*Subscript[c, 7, 5]*Subscript[d, 5, 2]*Subscript[e, 2, 2] + Subscript[b, 6]*Subscript[c, 6, 6]*Subscript[d, 6, 2]*Subscript[e, 2, 2] + 
  Subscript[b, 7]*Subscript[c, 7, 6]*Subscript[d, 6, 2]*Subscript[e, 2, 2] + Subscript[b, 7]*Subscript[c, 7, 7]*Subscript[d, 7, 2]*Subscript[e, 2, 2] + 
  Subscript[b, 3]*Subscript[c, 3, 3]*Subscript[d, 3, 3]*Subscript[e, 3, 2] + Subscript[b, 5]*Subscript[c, 5, 3]*Subscript[d, 3, 3]*Subscript[e, 3, 2] + 
  Subscript[b, 6]*Subscript[c, 6, 3]*Subscript[d, 3, 3]*Subscript[e, 3, 2] + Subscript[b, 7]*Subscript[c, 7, 3]*Subscript[d, 3, 3]*Subscript[e, 3, 2] + 
  Subscript[b, 5]*Subscript[c, 5, 4]*Subscript[d, 4, 3]*Subscript[e, 3, 2] + Subscript[b, 6]*Subscript[c, 6, 4]*Subscript[d, 4, 3]*Subscript[e, 3, 2] + 
  Subscript[b, 7]*Subscript[c, 7, 4]*Subscript[d, 4, 3]*Subscript[e, 3, 2] + Subscript[b, 5]*Subscript[c, 5, 5]*Subscript[d, 5, 3]*Subscript[e, 3, 2] + 
  Subscript[b, 6]*Subscript[c, 6, 5]*Subscript[d, 5, 3]*Subscript[e, 3, 2] + Subscript[b, 7]*Subscript[c, 7, 5]*Subscript[d, 5, 3]*Subscript[e, 3, 2] + 
  Subscript[b, 6]*Subscript[c, 6, 6]*Subscript[d, 6, 3]*Subscript[e, 3, 2] + Subscript[b, 7]*Subscript[c, 7, 6]*Subscript[d, 6, 3]*Subscript[e, 3, 2] + 
  Subscript[b, 7]*Subscript[c, 7, 7]*Subscript[d, 7, 3]*Subscript[e, 3, 2] + Subscript[b, 5]*Subscript[c, 5, 4]*Subscript[d, 4, 4]*Subscript[e, 4, 2] + 
  Subscript[b, 6]*Subscript[c, 6, 4]*Subscript[d, 4, 4]*Subscript[e, 4, 2] + Subscript[b, 7]*Subscript[c, 7, 4]*Subscript[d, 4, 4]*Subscript[e, 4, 2] + 
  Subscript[b, 5]*Subscript[c, 5, 5]*Subscript[d, 5, 4]*Subscript[e, 4, 2] + Subscript[b, 6]*Subscript[c, 6, 5]*Subscript[d, 5, 4]*Subscript[e, 4, 2] + 
  Subscript[b, 7]*Subscript[c, 7, 5]*Subscript[d, 5, 4]*Subscript[e, 4, 2] + Subscript[b, 6]*Subscript[c, 6, 6]*Subscript[d, 6, 4]*Subscript[e, 4, 2] + 
  Subscript[b, 7]*Subscript[c, 7, 6]*Subscript[d, 6, 4]*Subscript[e, 4, 2] + Subscript[b, 7]*Subscript[c, 7, 7]*Subscript[d, 7, 4]*Subscript[e, 4, 2] + 
  Subscript[b, 4]*(Subscript[c, 4, 2]*Subscript[d, 2, 2]*Subscript[e, 2, 2] + Subscript[c, 4, 3]*Subscript[d, 3, 2]*Subscript[e, 2, 2] + 
    Subscript[c, 4, 4]*Subscript[d, 4, 2]*Subscript[e, 2, 2] + Subscript[c, 4, 3]*Subscript[d, 3, 3]*Subscript[e, 3, 2] + Subscript[c, 4, 4]*Subscript[d, 4, 3]*Subscript[e, 3, 2] + 
    Subscript[c, 4, 4]*Subscript[d, 4, 4]*Subscript[e, 4, 2]) + Subscript[b, 5]*Subscript[c, 5, 5]*Subscript[d, 5, 5]*Subscript[e, 5, 2] + 
  Subscript[b, 6]*Subscript[c, 6, 5]*Subscript[d, 5, 5]*Subscript[e, 5, 2] + Subscript[b, 7]*Subscript[c, 7, 5]*Subscript[d, 5, 5]*Subscript[e, 5, 2] + 
  Subscript[b, 6]*Subscript[c, 6, 6]*Subscript[d, 6, 5]*Subscript[e, 5, 2] + Subscript[b, 7]*Subscript[c, 7, 6]*Subscript[d, 6, 5]*Subscript[e, 5, 2] + 
  Subscript[b, 7]*Subscript[c, 7, 7]*Subscript[d, 7, 5]*Subscript[e, 5, 2] + Subscript[b, 6]*Subscript[c, 6, 6]*Subscript[d, 6, 6]*Subscript[e, 6, 2] + 
  Subscript[b, 7]*Subscript[c, 7, 6]*Subscript[d, 6, 6]*Subscript[e, 6, 2] + Subscript[b, 7]*Subscript[c, 7, 7]*Subscript[d, 7, 6]*Subscript[e, 6, 2] + 
  Subscript[b, 7]*Subscript[c, 7, 7]*Subscript[d, 7, 7]*Subscript[e, 7, 2]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide your expression as copyable code. As it stands, anyone wanting to help you will have to type the entire expression by hand

Comment: Done, but it does not look pretty...

Comment: Could nest ‘Collect’ perhaps. The target variables would be b’s on the outside and c’s in the nested one.

Answer (score 3):

```
expr=Subscript[b, 2] Subscript[c, 2,2] Subscript[d, 2,2] Subscript[e, 2,2]+Subscript[b, 3] (Subscript[c, 3,2] Subscript[d, 2,2] Subscript[e, 2,2]+Subscript[c, 3,3] (Subscript[d, 3,2] Subscript[e, 2,2]+Subscript[d, 3,3] Subscript[e, 3,2]))+Subscript[b, 4] (Subscript[c, 4,2] Subscript[d, 2,2] Subscript[e, 2,2]+Subscript[c, 4,3] (Subscript[d, 3,2] Subscript[e, 2,2]+Subscript[d, 3,3] Subscript[e, 3,2])+Subscript[c, 4,4] (Subscript[d, 4,2] Subscript[e, 2,2]+Subscript[d, 4,3] Subscript[e, 3,2]+Subscript[d, 4,4] Subscript[e, 4,2]))+Subscript[b, 5] (Subscript[c, 5,2] Subscript[d, 2,2] Subscript[e, 2,2]+Subscript[c, 5,3] (Subscript[d, 3,2] Subscript[e, 2,2]+Subscript[d, 3,3] Subscript[e, 3,2])+Subscript[c, 5,4] (Subscript[d, 4,2] Subscript[e, 2,2]+Subscript[d, 4,3] Subscript[e, 3,2]+Subscript[d, 4,4] Subscript[e, 4,2])+Subscript[c, 5,5] (Subscript[d, 5,2] Subscript[e, 2,2]+Subscript[d, 5,3] Subscript[e, 3,2]+Subscript[d, 5,4] Subscript[e, 4,2]+Subscript[d, 5,5] Subscript[e, 5,2]))
```

---

The expression above is from your Latex example. The code example you gave is a lot easier and I will focus instead on the Latex example.

To visualize the level and terms you can use [`Framed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Framed.html)

#### Level 1

**Visualize the terms at level 1 :**

```
Replace[expr , a_*(b_ + c_) :> a*Framed[b + c], 1]
```

[image]

Notice the last product is not framed because it is a product and not a sum:

**Obtaining those terms:**

```
Cases[expr , a_*(b_ + c_) :> (b + c), 1]
```

[image]

**Visualizing the terms and obtaining** them at the same time using [`Reap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) and [`Sow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html)

```
Reap[Replace[expr , a_*(b_ + c_) :> (Sow[b + c]; a*Framed[b + c]), 1]]
```

[image]

#### Sums at the next level in the expression:

**Note:** Note the usage of {3} which tells Mathematica to look only at expressions at level 3. If I used 3 instead Mathematica would consider all sub expressions from 1 to 3.

**Note** I used {3} instead of {2} because I did not see any new sub expressions at level 2.

```
Reap[Replace[expr , a_*(b_ + c_) :> (Sow[b + c]; a*Framed[b + c]), {3}]]
```

[image]